# Can I use Oracle SQL to plot actual dates from Schedule Information?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I asked [this question in regard to SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612480/can-i-use-sql-to-plot-actual-dates-based-on-schedule-information), but what's the answer for an Oracle environment (10g)?

If I have a table containing schedule information that implies particular dates, is there a SQL statement that can be written to convert that information into actual rows, using something like MSSQL's Commom Table Expressions, perhaps?

Consider a payment schedule table with these columns:

- **StartDate** - the date the schedule begins (1st payment is due on this date)
- **Term** - the length in months of the schedule
- **Frequency** - the number of months between recurrences
- **PaymentAmt** - the payment amount :-)

```
SchedID  StartDate    Term  Frequency  PaymentAmt
-------------------------------------------------
1        05-Jan-2003  48    12         1000.00 
2        20-Dec-2008  42    6          25.00
```

Is there a single SQL statement to allow me to go from the above to the following?

```
                              Running
SchedID Payment  Due          Expected
        Num      Date         Total
--------------------------------------
1       1        05-Jan-2003  1000.00
1       2        05-Jan-2004  2000.00
1       3        05-Jan-2005  3000.00
1       4        05-Jan-2006  4000.00
2       1        20-Dec-2008  25.00
2       2        20-Jun-2009  50.00
2       3        20-Dec-2009  75.00
2       4        20-Jun-2010  100.00
2       5        20-Dec-2010  125.00
2       6        20-Jun-2011  150.00
2       7        20-Dec-2011  175.00
```

Your thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't set out to answer my own question, but I'm doing work with Oracle now and I have had to learn some new Oracle-flavored things.

Anyway, the CONNECT BY statement is really nice--yes, much nicer than MSSQL's hierchical query approach, and using that construct, I was able to produce a very clean query that does what I was looking for:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
     t.SchedID
    ,level as PaymentNum
    ,add_months(T.StartDate,level - 1) as DueDate
    ,(level * t.PaymentAmt) as RunningTotal
FROM SchedTest t
CONNECT BY level <= (t.Term / t.Frequency)
ORDER BY t.SchedID, level
```

My only remaining issue is that I had to use DISTINCT because I couldn't figure out how to select my rows from DUAL (the affable one-row Oracle table) instead of from my table of schedule data, which has at least 2 rows. If I could do the above with FROM DUAL, then my DISTINCT indicator wouldn't be necessary. Any thoughts?

Other than that, I think this is pretty nice. Et tu?

Answer (score 1):

Oracle actually has syntax for hierarchical queries using the CONNECT BY clause.  SQL Server's use of the WITH clause looks like a hack in comparison:

```
    SELECT t.SchedId,
           CASE LEVEL
             WHEN 1 THEN
               t.StartDate
             ELSE
               ADD_MONTHS(t.StartDate, t.frequency)
             END 'DueDate',
           CASE LEVEL
             WHEN 1 THEN
               t.PaymentAmt
             ELSE
               SUM(t.paymentAmt)
           END 'RunningExpectedTotal'
      FROM PaymentScheduleTable t
     WHERE t.PaymentNum <= t.Term / t.Frequency
CONNECT BY PRIOR t.startdate = t.startdate
  GROUP BY t.schedid, t.startdate, t.frequency, t.paymentamt
  ORDER BY t.SchedId, t.PaymentNum
```

I'm not 100% on that - I'm more confident about using:

```
    SELECT t.SchedId,
           t.StartDate 'DueDate',
           t.PaymentAmt 'RunningExpectedTotal'
      FROM PaymentScheduleTable t
     WHERE t.PaymentNum <= t.Term / t.Frequency
CONNECT BY PRIOR t.startdate = t.startdate
  ORDER BY t.SchedId, t.PaymentNum
```

...but it doesn't include the logic to handle when you're dealing with the 2nd+ entry in the chain to add months & sum the amounts.  The summing could be done with GROUP BY CUBE or ROLLUP depending on the detail needed.

Comment: I'm trying what you've suggested but I'm not having much luck. The second query causes an infinite loop. How do I avoid that?

Comment: I wasn't sure if CONNECT BY PRIOR support pointing at the same column - don't have Oracle to test with.  I was also missing "where q.PaymentNum <= s.Term / s.Frequency"

Comment: I updated to connect by prior on the start date, as that's what's actually indicating order but I don't know if you can point to the same column.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why 5 payment days for schedid = 1 and 7 for scheid = 2?

48 /12 = 4 and 42 / 6 = 7. So I expected 4 payment days for schedid = 1.

Anyway I use the model clause:

```
create table PaymentScheduleTable 
( schedid   number(10)
, startdate date
, term      number(3)
, frequency number(3)
, paymentamt number(5)
);

insert into PaymentScheduleTable 
values (1,to_date('05-01-2003','dd-mm-yyyy')
, 48
, 12
, 1000);

insert into PaymentScheduleTable 
values (2,to_date('20-12-2008','dd-mm-yyyy')
, 42
, 6
, 25);

commit;
```

And now the select with model clause:

```
select schedid, to_char(duedate,'dd-mm-yyyy') duedate, expected, i paymentnum
from   paymentscheduletable
model  
partition by (schedid)
dimension by (1 i)
measures (
  startdate duedate
, paymentamt expected
, term 
, frequency) 
rules 
( expected[for i from 1 to term[1]/frequency[1] increment 1] 
  = nvl(expected[cv()-1],0) + expected[1]
, duedate[for i from 1 to term[1]/frequency[1] increment 1] 
  = add_months(duedate[1], (cv(i)-1) * frequency[1])
)
order by schedid,i;
```

This outputs:

```
   SCHEDID DUEDATE      EXPECTED PAYMENTNUM
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1 05-01-2003       1000          1
         1 05-01-2004       2000          2
         1 05-01-2005       3000          3
         1 05-01-2006       4000          4
         2 20-12-2008         25          1
         2 20-06-2009         50          2
         2 20-12-2009         75          3
         2 20-06-2010        100          4
         2 20-12-2010        125          5
         2 20-06-2011        150          6
         2 20-12-2011        175          7


11 rows selected.
```

Comment: You're right about SchedID 1. The example in the question should only have 4 payments, not 5. I'm changing that.